# VB.NET MYSQL Multiple Queries

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have vb.net desktop app that uses mysql. I can connect remotely without any problem. I have timer control that query the database every 10 secs. Now I want to execute multiple
Functions without using multiple connections.

```vb
Private Sub Timer__Tick()...
    call GET_QUEUED_EMAILS
    call Function2
    Call Function3
End sub
```

sample function:

```vb
Public Function GET_QUEUED_EMAILS(ByVal sql As String)
    Try
             ' Load From DB
            GlobalFunctions.db_connect()
            Dim reader As New MySqlDataReader
            Dim command As MySqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
            command.CommandText = sql

            reader = command.ExecuteReader
            If (reader.HasRows) Then
                While (reader.Read())

                       message_id = reader(0).ToString
                       message_status = reader(2).ToString

                    Exit While
                End While
                reader.Close()
                GlobalFunctions.connection.Close()
               call another function here....
            Else
                reader.Close()
                GlobalFunctions.connection.Close()

            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
           MessageBox.Show("Error" & ex.Message)
        End Try

End Sub'
```

Comment: What about calling the other functions that you need within your function on a timer that opens and closes the connection?

Comment: Read about [Connection Pooling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html) and try to implement their suggestions

Answer (score 0):

use three timers when the first timer ends starts the second timer

```
Private Sub Timer1__Tick()...
    call GET_QUEUED_EMAILS
    Timer2.Start
    Timer1.Stop
End sub
Private Sub Timer2__Tick()...
    call Function2
    Timer3.Start
    Timer2.Stop
End sub
Private Sub Timer3__Tick()...
    call Function3
    Timer3.Start
End sub
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this deals with using a single connection?

Comment: because with timers like this you preform queries one by one